# Directory was created instead of file

Tags: java, android, file

i want to create new file but instead it will create directory... i tried many check and ways.. in different part of my application create new file works fine...

```
public void copyDatabaseFromAssets() throws IOException {
            InputStream inputStream = app.getAssets().open(Static.DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
            File directory = new File(getInternalDatabaseFolder());
            boolean exist = directory.exists();
            boolean isDirecotry = directory.isDirectory();
            boolean isFile = directory.isFile();
            if(!directory.exists())directory.mkdirs();
            File targetFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(),Static.DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
            boolean exist2 = targetFile.exists();
            boolean isDirecotry2 = targetFile.isDirectory();
            boolean isFile2 = targetFile.isFile();
            boolean created = targetFile.createNewFile();
            FileTool.copyDataBaseFromAssets(inputStream,targetFile);
        }
```

Debug ->

```
directory = /data/data/***/databases   
exist = true    
isDirectory = true   
isFile = false

targetFile = /data/data/***/databases/database.sqlite   
exist2 = true    
isDirectory2 = true
isFile2 = false    
created = false
```

Error ->

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/***/databases/database.sqlite: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing `isDirecotry2` and `isFile2` ?

Comment: Try removing `boolean created = targetFile.createNewFile();` Depending on what you use in `copyDataBaseFromAssets`, the file might automatically get created.

Comment: i edited question, debug is fine

Comment: i removed createNewFile().. still i get directory

Comment: Maybe you created this file as directory (ie. by accident while testing), and it stayed as directory

Comment: oh my.. marcin is right :D ..bad mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exist2` indicates it is already existing and `isDirectory2` that it is a folder. Try deleting `database.sqlite` and run the same code again

Comment: i already create a file before, then i forgot delete this bad directory.. thx to you as well